# Usando MySQL como criar um Select que busque palavras "juntas"

Tags: mysql, sql, select, phpmyadmin

No MySQL como criar um select que busque palavras "juntas". Como por exemplo:

```
SELECT pessoa FROM tabela 
WHERE pessoa like '%josedasilva%'
```

Mas dessa forma não retorna nada. Pois está cadastrado como "José da Silva". Gostaria que retornasse mais registros, abrangendo uma pesquisa mais ampla, ou seja, não tão especifica.

**A busca é feita através de um campo html via php.**

Comment: Acredito que seja ideal usar o [`Full-Text Search`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/fulltext-search.html), ao invés do `LIKE`.

Comment: Acho qué menos ampla a pesquisa com Full-Text.
Select pessoa from tabela WHERE MATCH(pessoa) AGAINST (' josedasilva' IN BOOLEAN MODE)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT pessoa FROM tabela 
WHERE pessoa like '%jose%' or  like '%da%' or  like '%silva%'
```

ou

```
SELECT pessoa FROM tabela 
WHERE pessoa like '%jose_da_silva%'
```

Deu certo asim:

```
select pessoa from tabela where (replace(pessoa, ' ', '')) like replace('%josedasilva%', ' ', '')
```

Comment: A busca é feita através de um campo html via php. Como é possível utilizar dessa forma?

Comment: substituta os espaços em brancos por _ !!!  esse ultimo sql funciona perfeitamente.

Comment: REPLACE('Jose da silva',' ','_')

Comment: Dessa forma deu certo:
select pessoa
from tabela 
where (replace(pessoa, ' ', '')) like replace('%josedasilva%', ' ', '')

Comment: Então marca para outras psesos ver que deu certo.

Answer (score 0):

Como diferenciar "Alex Andre" de "Alexandre"?

O mais proximo que conseguiria chegar é achar pessoas sem o caracater de espaco. Mas isso pode implicar em pessoas que estao apenas com o primeiro nome salvo.

```
select pessoa from tabela where pessoa not like '% %'
```

Comment: Se pesquisar por "Alexandre" gostaria que retornasse os dois termos caso existisse: "Alex Andre" e "Alexandre". Um pesquisa bem ampla.

Answer (score 0):

Utilize `%` para substituir caracteres na pesquisa.

```
SELECT pessoa FROM tabela 
WHERE pessoa like '%jose%da%silva%'
```

No seguinte cenário, o utilizador escreveu `jose da silva` na caixa de pesquisa. A função `str_replace()` é utilizada para substituir `espaço` por `%`:

```
<?php
 $pesquisa = "jose da silva"; 
 $pesquisaSQL = "%" . str_replace(" ", "%", $pesquisa) . "%";
?>
```

Se o utilizador escrever `josedasilva` diretamente na pesquisa, ele está fazendo uma pesquisa errada, por isso ignore esse facto.

Comment: A busca é feita através de um campo via php. Então não é possível utilizar dessa forma.

Comment: Substitua espaços por % e acrescente % no princípio e no fim

Answer (score 0):

user3499898

É muito relativo, da forma como disse você precisaria retirar os acentos e os espaços, isso pode ser feito com o REPLACE trocando as letras para minúsculas.
Segue exemplo: 

`SELECT pessoa 
FROM tabela 
WHERE LOWER(pessoa) = LOWER(REPLACE('josedasilva', ' ', ''))`